# NHibernate Issue: List of subclass picking up all classes in table-per-class-hierarchy

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm

We have a class, SpecialContainer (itself a subclass of Container), that has a list of contents of type TypeThreeContent:

```
class SpecialContainer {
  private IList<TypeThreeContent> _contents = new List< TypeThreeContent >();
}
```

TypeThreeContent is just a subclass of BaseContent, both of which have some uninteresting properties I've omitted for simplicitly.  Here's the mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-​2.2">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-​2.2" discriminator-value="0" name="AbstractBaseContent" table="tblContent">
    <id access="field" name="_id" type="System.Int32" unsaved-value="0">
      <column name="ContentID" />
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <discriminator type="Int32">
      <column name="FormsType" />
    </discriminator>
    <subclass name="TypeOneContent" discriminator-value="1">
    </subclass>
    <subclass name="TypeTwoContent" discriminator-value="2">
    </subclass>
    <subclass name="TypeThreeContent" discriminator-value="3">
    </subclass>
  </class>



<class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-​2.2" discriminator-value="-1" name="BaseContainer" table="tblContainers">
    ...
    <subclass name="SpecialContainer" discriminator-value="1">
      <join table="tblSpecialContainers">
        ...
        <bag access="field" cascade="none" inverse="true" lazy="true" name="_contents">
          <key>
            <column name="ContainerId" />
          </key>
          <one-to-many class="TypeThreeContent" />
        </bag>
       </join>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The problem I'm having is that rows with other discriminator values (i.e. 1 and 2) are getting picked up in NH's fetching of the list.  I used NHProf to verify that the SQL query is not specifying a discriminator in its criteria:

SELECT ...
FROM   dbo.tblContent content0_
WHERE  content0_.SpecialContainerId = 140 /* @p0 */

What's going on here?

Comment: Are `SpecialContainer`, `TypeOneContent`, etc. the real names of the classes, or have they been changed to protect the innocent?  I'm not sure I've ever seen a table structure like this, and I'm trying to understand the reason behind it to know whether you're on the right track or not.  It might help if we had the real names - or at least some way to better understand the data you're trying to model.

Comment: I'm working with him on this.

Comment: Yes, it's been "sanitized" :-(  This is a template and content system.

There is an abstract BaseTemplate, and then three types of templates (PaymentTemplate, InstallmentTemplate and FormTemplate).  It is from these templates that instances of content are generated.  A SpecialContainer has a many-to-one reference to a PaymentContent (generated from a PaymentTemplate), another many-to-one reference to an InstallmentContent, and a one-to-many bag of FormContents.

Comment: It is the latter where the trouble creeps in.  We have PaymentContent, InstallmentContent and FormContent all mapped to the same tblContents table.  But through the one-to-many bag relationship, all rows belonging to the same ContainerId -- not just those discriminated as FormContents as indicated by the collection type -- are coming back.  That is, the PaymentContent rows in tblContents and the InstallmentContent rows in tblContents are brought back along with the FormContent rows.  Except all rows are interpreted as FormContent entities.